# SQL Join query with a null in Main table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys so in simple terms I have a Main table "A" and then another table "B".
All the data I want is basically from table A, but to figure one part out I need to join with B. My problem is although the column im joining with a column in B is correct, sometimes the column in A will be Null and essentially have no relation to column B.

example:

Table A

```
ID | NAME | SECTOR | HAIR | AGE
1  | John |  5     | RED  | 20
2  | Doe  |  3     |BROWN | 22
3  | Mary |        |RED   | 20 
4  | Eric |  5     | RED  | 45
```

Table B

```
ID | SectorID | SectorNme
1  |    5     |  Plumbing
2  |    3     |  Admin
```

Now the real table has more fields and  all but unfortunately cannot upload it due to privacy. But above is a simple idea what I wish to get at, now say I wish to get all people who are in plumbing and also have a null sector so my ideal return answer **i want would be John and Mary.**

But my WRONG query code which is

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM TableA  
left JOIN  TableB
ON TableA.SECTOR = TableB.SectorID
WHERE TableB.SectorNme= 'Plumbing' AND TableA.hair = 'red' AND tableA.age < 30
```

Obviously will just return John as Mary sectorID is null so no join. So this is probably a very SIMPLE fix but my brain is obviously not working so how can I go about including the likes of any NULL sectors from table A etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to be SectorName = Plumbin and hair = red OR sector null? AND of course age <30

```
WHERE ((TableB.SectorNme= 'Plumbing' AND TableA.hair = 'red') OR TableA.sector is null ) AND tableA.age < 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableA.SECTOR = TableB.SectorID AND
        TableB.SectorNme = 'Plumbing';
```

I doubt `SELECT DISTINCT` is actually necessary.  It incurs overhead, so if it is not needed, just use `SELECT`.

Comment: I think he wants null or plumbing

Comment: I'll try this, but I was wondering (I forgot to mention) I will have a few 'where' clauses in it too for TableA so e.g say TableA had the likes of hair color and age and i wanted to search for people with just red hair who are younger than 35 and are in plumbing or have no sector.

Comment: any where reference to the left joined table basically eliminates the left join. move all of those to the JOIN ON...

Answer (score 0):

I think you also want nulls. Try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableA.SECTOR = TableB.SectorID AND
        ISNULL(TableB.SectorNme, 'Plumbing') = 'Plumbing';
```